# Sony A7 II backfocus options

Tags: sony-a7ii

Is there any option to fix back focus for Sony A7 mark II?

I know that some Nikon cameras have AF Fine Tune/AF Micro Adjustment

Thanks

Comment: A better question might be why do you think you have back focus ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mirrorless cameras in general lack focus adjustment, because they can't benefit from it.  The purpose of that feature is to correct for the fact that DSLRs use a separate focusing sensor to determine whether the image is in focus, and it varies a bit from lens to lens because differences in focal length make that difference larger or smaller.

With a mirrorless camera, the sensor is responsible for focusing, so there's no error to compensate for.  So with a mirrorless camera, if your photos aren't in focus, either the lens is inherently soft or the camera didn't have time to focus or focused on the wrong thing, none of which would be fixed by a per-lens focusing offset.

Comment: There's also the possibilities that the focus elements in the lens are 'loose' and are moving between the time AF is completed and the photo is taken. Or that the AF system isn't fast enough to keep up with a moving target when using AF-C/Servo.